# Characterization of $L^\infty(\Omega)$ norm using $L^p(\Omega) $ norm.

Tags: reference-request, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ and $f \in L^\infty(\Omega)$. We know that if $\lambda(\Omega) < +\infty$ with $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$, we have the inclusion

$$L^\infty(\Omega) \subset L^p(\Omega), \quad \forall p \in [1,+\infty[.$$
and that this injection is continuous.

I am looking for references or a proof for the following property : $||f||_{L^\infty(\Omega)} = \underset{p \rightarrow + \infty}{\liminf} ||f||_{L^p(\Omega)}.$

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f\in L^{\infty}$. Then, $|f|\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$ almost everywhere and we get that

$$
\|f\|^p_p=\int |f|^p\textrm{d}\lambda\leq  \int \|f\|_{\infty}^p\textrm{d}\lambda=\lambda(\Omega)\|f\|^{p}_{\infty},
$$
implying that $\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\leq \|f\|_{\infty}$.

Similarly, for any $\|f\|_{\infty}>\varepsilon>0$, we have that $|f|\geq 1_{\{|f|\geq \|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon\}} (\|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon)$ and we get that
$$
\|f\|_p\geq \lambda(\{|f|\geq \|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon\})^{1/p}(\|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon)
$$
As $\lambda(\{|f|\geq \|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon\})>0,$ we get that
$$
\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p\geq \|f\|_{\infty}-\varepsilon,
$$
Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we get the result.